# Using a 2-hand weapon with one hand and Oversize Weapon Master: effect on parry

Tags: savage-worlds

In Savage Worlds there are several 2-handed meleé weapons and most of them have an effect on the character´s parry. For example, fighting with a Great Sword requires 2 hands and lowers your parry by one point while fighting with a Spear requires 2 hands and increases your parry by one point.

In some of the settings (I think the first one was *50 fathoms*) there is an edge (*Oversize Weapon Master*) that allows characters to use a 2-hand weapon in one hand ---without suffering a -4 penalty.

I wonder if using a 2-handed weapon with this edge should erase the effects on parry, both positive and negative. It seems intuitive to me that being able to use a sword or an axe with one hand means that you have more control on the big weapon (thus negating the -1 on parry) while using a spear with just one hold means that you cannot make as much stopping force as with two holding points (thus negating the +1 to parry).

I have not seen anything relevant in the core rules (but I do not have access to *50 fathoms* or the other settings) nor have I found any official position on this in the forums. If anyone has the right setting that clarifies this issue or has found anything relevant from an official source, I would be very grateful to know.

Comment: Great question. Not sure there is an 'official' answer, but could be wrong. I would houserule it depending on the source of the Parry modifier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Rules As Written**

The basic answer is no. The *Oversize Weapon Master* allows you to do it, it does not change the characteristics of the weapon.

**Ideas**

There are really two types of Spears, 1 handed which would be throw and used with a shield and 2 handed which could not.

The +1 Parry on a Spear probably comes from abstracting it reach and forcing your opposed to be further away. I can't see how using it with one handed changes this. If this is a normal one handed small spear then there should already be no reach bonus as it is shorter.

Forgetting about the fact that Great Swords is an incorrect naming (and the weight is off too) then the idea of the -1 is because of the over balancing from using this type of sword. I can't see why using it one handed would negative this, unless you where also well over the strength required. As you need a d10 strength normally you could house rule that some one with d12+2 strength does not have the penalty.

Comment: Or, without changing the numbers, the strength bonus balances out the penalty.